# Satis + Gitlab private project - after build no package is downloaded

Tags: gitlab, composer-php, gitlab-ci, satis

I hve a gitlab private project for a composer package that is published to its package registry via pipeline.

Now I want to use satis to create my repository and publish it to gitlab pages in order  to make the private package available, so i made a new project and created the following pipeline.
Problem is, pipeline works correctly and my custom repository is published to pages **BUT** it is empty: by web-browsing it seems that no package is available.

Running commands locally gives no error, but actually no `dist` folder is created in satis build directory.

Package latest version is present in both the project releases and package registry.

Just for the sake of test, using a wrong group id in `satis.json` lead to the error

```
The "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/group/<wrong-group-id>/-/packages/composer/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/2 404 ):
  {"message":"404 Group Not Found"}
```

so I suppose that bot the group id and auth credentials used are working correctly, i.e. no "silent error" is happening during pipeline execution.

##### satis.json

```json
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/group/<group-id>/-/packages/composer/"
        }
    ],
    "require-all": true,
    "archive": {
        "directory": "dist",
        "format": "zip",
        "skip-dev": true
    }
}
```

##### .gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
stages:
  - build

pages:
  stage: build
  image: composer:2
  before_script:
    - composer install
    - composer config -g gitlab-oauth.gitlab.com ${PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}
  script:
    - composer satis:build satis.json ./public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, changing the `satis.json` entry for the repository in following way solved the problem, now every version of my package is downloaded to local `dist` folder and the web ui list them all.

```json
{
   "type": "vcs",
   "url": "https://gitlab.com/vendor/group/subgroup/project"
}
```